# How to Insert Data into REF linked Tables in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Here my types and tables,

```
create type Customer_t as object(
   cid char(6),
   cusname varchar(15),
   birthdate date,
   phone char(10),
   address varchar(50)
);

create type claim_t as object(
   claimno char(12),
   cdate date,
   amount number(8,2),
   claimant ref customer_t
);

create type Claim_ntab is table of claim_t;

create type policy_t as object(
    pid char(7),      
    sdate date,
    edate date,
    inscar ref car_t,
    premium number(6,2),
    claims claim_ntab
);

create table Policies of policy_t(
pid primary key,
inscar references Cars
)nested table claims store as  claims_ntable;
```

How to insert data into Policies table?

Comment: This question shows a lack of research. Using User-Defined DataTypes (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch_objs.htm), Using PL/SQL with Object Types (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm)

Comment: KC Wong, thanks for your comment. actually i want some example code only.that's why this question shows lack of research.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. The two links I provided should give you the answer you need. Search for INSERT in those two pages for examples. If you Google'd a bit you'd have found those pages yourself, hence I said there is a lack of research.

Comment: Hey KC Wong, thanks to your comment.